# Run VBScript in QTP continuously

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a qtp script with many subroutines and functions. I am automating a test of an application . The application requires testing multiple times for different set of data. Right 
now the script reads first set of data and continues until the script runs out. I cannot think of anything for the script to go back to the top of the script once it reaches to the end. It would be easy if everything was under a main method. There is no main method just multiple subroutines and function which runs from top to bottom of the script.

Comment: First question is this - what are you trying to accomplish by repeatedly executing the same test? Aside from this, you could use the OTA interface to repeatedly run the same test from a VB script, or you could use Recovery.Activate to execute a recovery scenario that restarts the test (probably not the best option).

Comment: @BrianJM I am testing multiple sets of similar data. Trying to create different users and enrolling to them in different services provided.

Comment: I see. I misunderstood the question. I thought you already had rows of data setup and you wanted to run the same rows repeatedly without interruption. You just need to set your run settings and setup the appropriate data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you're trying to data drive your test. If you have multiple lines in the data-table you can instruct QTP to run an action (or the whole test) for each line in the data-table.

To do this for test right click on the test in the test flow, select settings and choose the Run on all rows radio button.

[image: Setting for test iterations]
For the equivalent in actions this in right click -> Action Call Properties.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a script like:

```
Option Explicit : main

Sub main()
    Do
        ' This initializes a test for me. The test resides in an
        ' homebrew AutomatedTest object     
        Set automatedTest = [new AutomatedTest]
        automatedTest.Project = "XYZ"
        automatedTest.PickupFolder = "C:\TestScenarios\"
        automatedTest.Initialize

        ' This line starts my test
        automatedTest.Start

        Set automatedTest = Nothing

    Loop Until (CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup("Next file will be executed in 10 seconds." & vbNewLine & _
            "Press OK to execute immediately or Cancel to stop Autorun.", 10, "Autorun", 1 or 32 or 4096) = 2)  '2 = cancel
End sub
```

How you want to implement it, you can see for yourself, the `Do` / `Loop` action provides a continues loop, while the `WshShell.Popup` provides a way to cancel between tests and to continue if no action was taken after a certain amount of time. That comes in handy if you want to run tests unattended.

Answer (score 0):

Try 1. Run all rows option in Test->Settings->Run
 or
2. In your test,

Add below code 
totalrows=Datatable.getrowcount

for row=1 to totalrows
//entire test code
next